# Using Parameters in Failure Condition on TeamCity 2022.04.4

Tags: teamcity

I have a build configuration that runs on multiple branches. I would like to set a failure condition that compares code coverage numbers, *but only within the current branch*.

What i've done:

1. Added a build step that sets a custom parameter "CurrentBranch" to the value of the current branch (either `%teamcity.build.branch%` or `%teamcity.pullRequest.target.branch%` if its a PR build)
2. Added a build step that successfully adds a tag to the build (using the REST API) with the value of `%CurrentBranch%`.
3. Added a failure condition that compares the current code coverage with the last successful build with tag `%CurrentBranch%`
   [image: Note that the 'tag' input explicitly says that parameters can be used here.]

However, when I execute the build, I get a warning:

> Invalid settings for build failure on metric
>
> buildTag: Tag must be specified

If i explicitly set the tag in the "failure condition" properties to one of the branches, it works as expected.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried using the original `%teamcity.build.branch%` parameter. That did not produce the warning. So it seems to support parameters, but not parameters set during the build?

Edit: If I *initialize* my custom `%CurrentBranch%` parameter with `%teamcity.build.branch%` I no longer get the warning. Will need to check if (in the case of pull-requests) it actually uses the correct branch for metrics comparison.

The behavior still seems odd. If anyone can shine a little light on this, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Hi! There's difference between two kind of parameters: ones that could be calculated before build starts and ones which are set during build time. My guess that failure conditions work only with the first type of parameters

Comment: Thanks! My current theory goes as follows: Failure-Conditions are evaluated constantly (i.e. before and after every build step), so even before i set my CurrentBranch parameter. And the process that checks the failure condition remembers that it - at some point - did not have a value for the parameter and complains at the end. That explains why initializing the parameter removes the warning. I just hope that the condition is properly updated and does not stick to its initial value for all successive checks.. Haven't gotten around to testing that yet, though